How to Apply Generalized Stokes Theorem to a Vector Field Dependent on Position and Orientation?
Following this question, consider a vector field $\vec{\sigma}(\vec{r}, \hat{n})$ that is a function of both position $\vec{r}$ and orientation $\hat{n}$ in 3D space. This field is defined over a fixed control volume $V$ with a closed surface boundary $\partial V$.
I am interested in understanding how to apply the Generalized Stokes Theorem to this vector field, particularly in expressing the surface integral
$$\oint_{\partial V} \vec{\sigma}(\vec{r}, \hat{n}) \, dA = \int_{V} \,? \, dV \, , \tag{1}$$
where $\hat{n}$ is the outward unit normal vector at each point on the surface, in terms of a volume integral over $V$. Given that $\vec{\sigma}$ depends on position and orientation, I find it challenging to identify what $d\omega$ and manifold $M$ would correspond to in this context:
$$\oint_{\partial M} \omega = \int_{M} d\omega \, , \tag{2}$$
Can anyone provide me with insights or resources to help me translate this integral into the framework of the Generalized Stokes Theorem using classical vector calculus? I prefer to use the vector calculus language and avoid differential form notations.

It seems that $\sigma$ is only defined on the boundary $\partial V$? At a point in the interior of $V$, the normal $\hat{n}$ would not be defined. To use Stokes' theorem, you would need to extend $\sigma$ so that it's defined on the entirety of $V$.

@Frank, I'm not sure I fully understand. Could you please explain further? If we use the language of differential geometry, $\sigma$ maps five dimensions to three.

From my understanding, $\sigma$ is defined on $\partial V$ because for any point $v \in \partial V$, there is a normal vector $n(v)$ attached to this point, so we can evaluate $\sigma$ at $(v, n(v))$. This is why the integral $\int_{\partial V} \sigma$ makes sense. I don't see an analogous way to canonically define $\sigma$ over $V$, which we need for the integral $\int_V d\omega$ to bmake sense.
